# Idioms describing the entirety of something

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

What are some idioms that describe the full entirety of something, or the complete collection.

One would be "the whole nine yards" - what else?

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/the%20whole%20nine%20yards

Comment: Some context please? How would you use it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "List-type" question.

Comment: The full monty. The top and bottom of it. Soup-to-nuts. The whole enchilada. In the round.

Comment: Greg, just FYI, in my mind at least, *the whole nine yards* is usually in the context of a performance or a set of actions; to do all the actions or go above and beyond the call of duty is to "go the whole nine yards", at least in my mind. :) ...not usually in the context of a collection of things.

Comment: Also, I almost suggested "everything but the kitchen sink" for its irony, in that it sounds like *not* the entirety of something, but is usually used in a way that indicates that the collection is *more than complete*.

Answer (score 2):

The first ones that pop into my head are *the whole shebang*, and *the whole kit and kaboodle*.

Comment: I was going to answer, "the whole kit and kaboodle."  Grr, you stole my answer.  ;-)  Upvote for you.

Comment: I was surprised to see (according to online resources) that the more common spelling is *caboodle*... I've never seen it spelled that way, have you @BenjaminHarman?

Answer (score 1):

[*the whole works*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whole+works)

> Everything; the complete amount. *I cashed my paycheck and lost the whole works playing the ponies*. [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/whole+works)